# pandas groupby with cumsum does not build index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to use cumsum with groupby, it doesn't throw an error but it also doesn't create an index based on the groupby column.  Here's the code:

```
t = pandas.DataFrame(
    [["a",3], ["a", 5], ["a", 7], ["b",11], ["b", 13], ["b", 17]],
    columns=["labels", "fractions"]
)
display(t)
t.groupby("labels").cumsum()
```

Here's the output:

```
    labels  fractions
0   a   3
1   a   5
2   a   7
3   b   11
4   b   13
5   b   17

    fractions
0   3
1   8
2   15
3   11
4   24
5   41
```

I realize I can use the index in result (0,1,2,...) to find the labels, but I'm surprised groupby doesn't make the label the index

Comment: How looks expected output? Do you want `t['new'] = t.groupby("labels")['fractions'].cumsum()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If groupby made the label the index, it would be repeating the index, so instead it preserves the original index and then one can create an appropriate index as needed in the results.